# Windowsユーザプロファイル変更後のemacsのHOMEディレクトリの設定

Tags: windows, emacs

掲題についての質問です。
Windowsでユーザプロファイルを移したのですが、移行後のemacsのHOMEディレクトリの設定がうまくいきません。

ユーザプロファイルの場所を以下の通り変更しました。

- 移行前: `C:\Users\user`
- 移行後: `C:\Users\user.domain`

環境変数 HOMEも同様に C:\Users\user から C:\Users\user.domain に変更したのですが、
変更後のpathをemacsがHOMEディレクトリとして認識してくれません。

移行前の環境と違うところといえば、Pathがドット交じりなところかと思うのですが、
emacsでドット交じりのPathをHOMEディレクトリに指定するのは無理なのでしょうか?

Answer (score 2):

[Location of init file - GNU Emacs FAQ For MS Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/Location-of-init-file.html#Location-of-init-file) にあるように、
レジストリ `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\GNU\Emacs\HOME` で指定するのはどうでしょうか。

Comment: ごめんなさい、回答いただいてたのに気が付きませんでした。
出来ました、ありがとうございます!

Comment: @user35326 問題が解決した場合には、ヘルプを参考に回答を「承認」してみてください。 - 参考: [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)